# Hide ones command history from other users on a Linux server

Tags: linux, bash, users, command-history

When I log in via ssh on a Linux(Ubuntu) server, I notice that all the bash commands executed by other users on the server are saved in the command history. Is there a way that could allow me to hide the commands that I have typed in the command line from other users on the server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663078/disable-history-in-linux

Comment: Normally you can only see your own command history, not other users' histories.

Comment: The command history of the `root` user in *important*. If anything goes wrong, you can look at it and see why. In your case I would set up multiple users with `sudo` access instead (the commands are then logged in both private history and in the syslog).

Comment: @anuribs Then you're confusing UNIX users and physical users. _shrug_

Comment: @anuribs why do you want to hide your commands from other users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to hide your command history, but it's a bad idea to turn off history altogether as it is very useful. Here are three good ways to turn it off temporarily.

1. **Quickest solution**: Type `unset HISTFILE`

   That will prevent all commands run in the current login session from getting saved to the .bash_history file when you logout. Note that HISTFILE will get reset the next time you login, so history will be saved as usual. Also, note that this removes *all* commands from the session, including ones run before you typed unset HISTFILE, which may not be what you want. Another downside is that you cannot be sure you did it right until you logout as bash will still let you use the up arrow to see previous commands.
2. **Best solution**: type a space before a command

   Try it and then hit up arrow to see if it got added to your history. Some sites have it already set up so that such commands are not saved. If it does not work, add the line `export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth` to your .bashrc file. When you login in the future, commands that start with a space will be forgotten immediately.
3. **Easiest to remember**: Type `sh`

   That will start a subshell with the original Bourne shell. Any commands written in it (until you `exit`) will not be saved in your history. Anybody looking at your history file will be able to see that you ran sh (which is suspicious), but not see what you ran after that.

There are many other ways of doing this. You can even tell bash which commands to never remember (HISTIGNORE). See the man page for bash(1) and search for HIST to see lots of possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

The command line history for `bash` shell sessions are stored in the `~/.bash_history` file.  If this file does not exist, it is created with no read permissions for other users.

You may change the number of commands that `bash` saves into this file by setting the `HISTFILESIZE` environment variable. Setting it to zero will truncate the history file to zero size. The default is 500. Unsetting the `HISTFILE` (`unset HISTFILE`) variable will also prevent storing commands in the history file.

However, the current setup of the server you're describing (in the comments) is simply wrong.

There should be no reason to allow multiple users to log in and use an interactive shell on the `root` account.  Do consider using `sudo` instead, with multiple private user accounts!

The command history for `root`, whether for interactive sessions or when using `sudo`, is extremely precious, *especially* if you have multiple users with `root` access on the system.

Your team will want to know *exactly* what the `root` user has been up to since any misconfigurations or other mishaps performed by this user must best be investigated and fixed. With a command line history, it makes it much easier to find why something went wrong. The `sudo` utility additionally logs every invocation to the syslog facility for this reason, with timestamps and with full command line, and with the username of the user executing `sudo`.

**EDIT**: We recently started having issues with a fiber network on a cluster of Linux machines at work. It turned out that some drivers or other were replaced with the wrong version when a silly user with `sudo` access made an careless package upgrade. We were able to find this through looking at the system logs and the `sudo` timestamps therein. The "silly user" turned out to be nobody else other than myself!

Comment: setting `HISTSIZE=0` will delete all commands from history

Comment: @mik Right you are! Updating...

Answer (score 1):

Issue the following command after logging in:

```
HISTFILE=
```

This will block any subsequent commands from being logged to the history file.

Comment: Actually, no commands from the session will be stored as the history file is written to when the shell exits. But that's nitpicking.

Comment: @Kusalananda generally you are right, but `bash` can be configured to save each command immediately. Moreover, I did not say anything about previous commands, so my statement is true nevertheless ;)